# Notation - problems with interpretation

Tags: notation

How to interpret the following expression in the context of functions of two continuous random variables:

\begin{align*}
D= \left [(x,y) | g(x, y)< z \right ]
\end{align*}

Comment: We're missing the context here. Apparently, the set of pairs $(x,y)$ (of real numbers?) such the value of the (real-valued?) function of two variables $g$ at this pair  is less than $z$.

Comment: @Bernard I have edited my question and added the context.

Comment: But $z$  is a real number, not a random variable?

Comment: @Bernard This is just after example 5.27 at https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_2_4_functions.php